# Correct way to initialize HashMap and can HashMap hold different value types?

Tags: java, standards, hashmap

So I have two questions about `HashMap`s in Java:

1. What is the correct way to initialize a `HashMap`? I think it might be best in my situation to use:

   ```
   HashMap x = new HashMap();
   ```

   But Eclipse keeps suggesting that I use:

   ```
   HashMap<something, something> map = new HashMap();
   ```

   Which is better?
2. Can a `HashMap` hold different types of objects/data types as values? For example, would this work and be OK:

   ```
   map.put("one", 1);
   map.put("two", {1, 2});
   map.put("three", "hello");
   ```

   In the first `put()`, I want an `int` as a value, in the second an `int[]`, and third a string. Is this okay to do in Java with `HashMap`s? Also, is it okay to store a `HashMap` as a value within a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of type safety you need. The non-generic way of doing it is best done as:

```
 Map x = new HashMap();
```

Note that `x` is typed as a `Map`. this makes it much easier to change implementations (to a `TreeMap` or a `LinkedHashMap`) in the future.

You can use generics to ensure a certain level of type safety:

```
Map<String, Object> x = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

In Java 7 and later you can do

```
Map<String, Object> x = new HashMap<>();
```

The above, while more verbose, avoids compiler warnings. In this case the content of the `HashMap` can be any `Object`, so that can be `Integer`, `int[]`, etc. which is what you are doing.

If you are still using Java 6, [Guava Libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (although it is easy enough to do yourself) has a method called [`newHashMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap%28%29) which avoids the need to duplicate the generic typing information when you do a `new`. It infers the type from the variable declaration (this is a Java feature not available on constructors prior to Java 7).

By the way, when you add an int or other primitive, Java is autoboxing it. That means that the code is equivalent to:

```
 x.put("one", Integer.valueOf(1));
```

You can certainly put a `HashMap` as a value in another `HashMap`, but I think there are issues if you do it recursively (that is put the `HashMap` as a value in itself).

Comment: what is the difference between making a HashMap<String, Object> map = new... and Map<String, Object> map = new...? Or do they make the same thing?

Comment: They make the same thing, it is just that your reference is typed as a Map (the interface) instead of the HashMap (the implementation) so that the implementation can be easily changed without affecting more than one line of code.

Comment: Look at the answer of Basil. Map.of() is the best way for a static list of few elements, having initializer in call.

Answer (score 14):

This is a change made with Java 1.5. What you list first is the old way, the second is the new way.

By using HashMap you can do things like:

```
HashMap<String, Doohickey> ourMap = new HashMap<String, Doohickey>();

....

Doohickey result = ourMap.get("bob");
```

If you didn't have the types on the map, you'd have to do this:

```
Doohickey result = (Doohickey) ourMap.get("bob");
```

It's really very useful. It helps you catch bugs and avoid writing all sorts of extra casts. It was one of my favorite features of 1.5 (and newer).

You can still put multiple things in the map, just specify it as Map, then you can put any object in (a String, another Map, and Integer, and three MyObjects if you are so inclined).

Comment: You've had me up until the last paragraph. "lists with little 'l'" are called arrays; and they are most definitely objects in Java.

Comment: You mention that to put multiple things in the map, I should just specify it as a Map. Why couldn't I use HashMap?

Comment: @ChssPly76: "arrays". That's the term. I couldn't remember it and went with my best guess at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: @hatorade: What I meant was just use Map instead of Map<String, Integer>. If you leave off the types the map will hold, you get basically Map<Object, Object>. You can use any kind of Map you'd like (HashMap, TreeMap, MyCustomMap, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is recommending that you declare the type of the HashMap because that enforces some type safety.  Of course, it sounds like you're trying to avoid type safety from your second part.

If you want to do the latter, try declaring map as `HashMap<String,Object>`.

Comment: is an int considered an object..?

Comment: "int"s are not objects, it's a primitive type. All the primitives (int, double, long, short...) have an object version you can use (Integer, Double, Long, Short). Java 1.5+ will even do the conversion between int and Integer for you so you don't have to worry about it (most of the time, look up "autoboxing").

Comment: autoboxing will convert int[] into an Object.

Comment: int[] is already an Object; surely you meant single `int` variable

Answer (score 3):

The way you're writing it is equivalent to

```
HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

What goes inside the brackets is you communicating to the compiler what you're going to put in the HashMap so that it can do error checking for you.  If Object, Object is what you actually want (probably not) you should explicitly declare it.  In general you should be as explicit as you can with the declaration to facilitate error checking by the compiler.  What you've described should probably be declared like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

That way you at least declare that your keys are going to be strings, but your values can be anything.  Just remember to use a cast when you get a value back out.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd one is using generics which came in with Java 1.5. It will reduce the number of casts in your code & can help you catch errors at compiletime instead of runtime. That said, it depends on what you are coding. A quick & dirty map to hold a few objects of various types doesn't need generics. But if the map is holding objects all descending from a type other than Object, it can be worth it.

The prior poster is incorrect about the array in a map. An array is actually an object, so it is a valid value.

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("one",1); // autoboxed to an object
map.put("two", new int[]{1,2} ); // array of ints is an object
map.put("three","hello"); // string is an object
```

Also, since HashMap is an object, it can also be a value in a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap can hold any object as a value, even if it is another HashMap. Eclipse is suggesting that you declare the types because that is the recommended practice for Collections. under Java 5. You are free to ignore Eclipse's suggestions.

Under Java 5, an int (or any primitive type) will be [autoboxed](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) into an Integer (or other corresponding type) when you add it to a collection. Be careful with this though, as there are some catches to using autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is suggesting you to define `generic type` so that you can have `type safety`. You can write

```
Map m = new HashMap();
```

which does not ensure type safety but following will ensure type safety

```
Map<Object,Object> = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

The `Object` can be any type such as `String`, `Integer` etc.

Answer (score 1):

## `Map.of` literals

As of Java 9, there is yet another way to instantiate a `Map`. You can create an unmodifiable map from zero, one, or several pairs of objects in a single-line of code. This is quite convenient in many situations.

For an empty `Map` that cannot be modified, call [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of()). Why would you want an empty set that cannot be changed? One common case is to avoid returning a NULL where you have no valid content.

For a single key-value pair, call [`Map.of( myKey , myValue )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)). For example, `Map.of( "favorite_color" , "purple" )`.

For multiple key-value pairs, use a series of key-value pairs. ``Map.of( "favorite_foreground_color" , "purple" , "favorite_background_color" , "cream" )`.

If those pairs are difficult to read, you may want to use `Map.of` and pass [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects.

Note that we get back an object of the `Map` interface. We do not know the underlying concrete class used to make our object. Indeed, the Java team is free to used different concrete classes for different data, or to vary the class in future releases of Java.

The rules discussed in other Answers still apply here, with regard to type-safety. You declare your intended types, and your passed objects must comply. If you want values of various types, use [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html).

```
Map< String , Color > preferences = Map.of( "favorite_color" , Color.BLUE ) ;
```

Comment: This is the most elegant way for HashMap initializers with a handfull of elements, without using double brace initialization, and even without any additional package dependency!

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question: Yes a HashMap can hold different types of objects. Whether that's a good idea or not depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

That said, your example won't work. The int value is not an Object. You have to use the Integer wrapper class to store an int value in a HashMap

Comment: In Java 5+, the compiler will do that for you.

Comment: It'll work in Java 5, which he's using since he's getting warnings about not having parameterized the map, with autoboxing.