# Storing different types of arguments in HashMap

Tags: java, android

I am using following code:

```
public boolean  initialSetupDone;
public Currency defaultCurrency;
public String   userId;

final String  kProfileSetupDoneKey  = "kProfileSetupDone";
final String  kDefaultCurrencyKey   = "kDefaultCurrency";
final String  kUserIdKey            = "kUserIdKey";
```

`String` values are the keys while others are the values.

Please tell me how can i store these values as `HashMap`. I have tried to do it with `Dictionary`, but can't find any good way to do it.

How can i do that

Best Regards

Comment: Possibly a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347949/correct-way-to-initialize-hashmap-and-can-hashmap-hold-different-value-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, but is usually not a good idea to mix types in a map:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(kProfileSetupDoneKey  , initialSetupDone);
// etc...
```

Comment: And also note that value of Map should be an Object, thus you should change initialSetupDone to Boolean instead of primitive boolean.

Comment: This is not needed because of Java Auto-Boxing feature. The primitive type will be converted automatically to its corresponding class type.